# Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: message to forward not found

Tags: python, py-telegram-bot-api, telebot

When I write 1, the bot should forward a certain file from the channel, but the bot cannot find this very file.

```
import telebot
from telebot import types


bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'hello')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text', 'forward'])
def send_message(message):
    if message.text == '1':
        bot.forward_message(message.chat.id, from_chat_id='@smth', message_id=1) 


bot.polling()
```

I am almost one hundred percent sure that the problem is "message_id". Namely, the bot cannot find that message in the channel (As could be understood from the description of the problem). If I'm not mistaken, message_id is "https://t.me /{channel name}/{message_id}" if so, then I took the correct id